Display one field in JSON as multi line with Angular
I have a textarea component in Angular and i want to display its value (a JSON string) through [{ngModel}]. The result is image belowenter image description here
What i want is the field "Message" display as below
This image i've edited by MS Paint
Can anyone help me? Thank a lot.
The actual result is fist image. What i want is the second image.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens

I dont see any difference between first and second image, are they correct?

I’m voting to close this question because this post is not well written, has duplicate images where the problem could be explained with words

In a text area the character \n makes a new line.
It's looks like really the property of your object are a "literal" "\n". I imagine you have,e.g. (see the double slash)
{"Message":"ID 1000\\nBKS29...."}

And you need
{"Message":"ID 1000\nBKS29...."}

You can use replace
data={Message:data.Message.replace("\\n",\"n")}

